# Bluetooth LE audio development with Bluez 5.66

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have tried initial BAP support with BlueZ 5.66 as mentioned in the https://www.bluez.org/le-audio-support/

But it fails at experimental ISO socket support all the time whenever I try to create a media endpoint with pac_sink and pac_source UUID in /profile/audio/media.c

**profiles/audio/media.c:media_endpoint_create() Unable initialize endpoint for UUID 00002bc9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb**

Initial level, Our device need to act as CIS source and i have nrf5340 audio DK to connect with and check the LE audio behavior.

**Device details:**

**OS :** Linux username 5.4.210 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 26 12:43:31 IST 2024 aarch64 GNU/Linux

**BlueZ ver :** 5.66 (--enable-experimental and added kernel experimental in main.conf)

**Pipewire :** 0.3.59 (-Dbluez5-codec-lc3=enabled)

**lc3 codec :** 1.0.4 (https://github.com/google/liblc3)

Do we need to update anything ?

Comment: If you are serious about developing BLE Audio, you should always use the latest version of BlueZ ([5.72](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git)) or even the latest from the git repository. The best place to ask questions about the current development of BlueZ is the [mailing list](https://www.bluez.org/development/lists/).